# Find only one subset sum with a specified value in python for large sets

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, combinatorics

how can I optimize my code for a large set (10000 elements)?

```
found = False


def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[]):
    global found
    s = sum(partial)

    # check if the partial sum is equals to target
    if s == target:
        print("sum(%s)=%s" % (partial, target))
        raise Exception('element found')
    if s >= target:
        return  # if we reach the number why bother to continue

    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        n = numbers[i]
        remaining = numbers[i+1:]
        subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n])
```

For example, for 50 elements it takes 41 seconds.

Comment: How large are the numbers and the target?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Would you mind adding some examples? For instance if `numbers` is `[1, 2, 9, 3, 4]` and `target` is 5, what do you expect to see? an `Exception` because 1+4 or 2+3 = 5 or nothing because no _contiguous_ elements sum to 5?